# Проблема с hasforeignkey

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Как-то не дается мне `Entity Framework`. Итак определил модели так:

```
[Table("Accounts")]
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TaskProto> Tasks { get; set; }
}

[Table("Groups")]
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TaskProto> Tasks { get; set; }    
}

[Table("Tasks")]
public class TaskProto
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountId;
    public int GroupId;
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent таков:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskProto>().HasRequired(p => p.Account).WithMany(b => b.Tasks).HasForeignKey(t => t.AccountId);
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskProto>().HasRequired(p => p.Group).WithMany(b => b.Tasks).HasForeignKey(t=>t.GroupId);
```

И все не работает, просто программа пропускает кучу строк и отрисовывает не до конца инициализированную форму. Никаких ошибок не выдает. Если убрать `HasForeignKey` хотя бы что-то работает, естественно зависимые объекты в `TaskProto` не подтягиваются. Уже перелопатил кучу материалов, делаю вроде всё как по учебнику. ЧЯДНТ?

**Up**

Попробовал вот так:

```
[Table("Tasks")]
public class TaskProto
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Account_Id")]
    public int AccountId;
    [Column("Group_Id")]
    public int GroupId;
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TaskProto() { }
}
```

```cs
            modelBuilder.Entity<TaskProto>().HasRequired(p => p.Account).WithMany(b => b.Tasks).Map(m => m.MapKey("Account_Id"));
            modelBuilder.Entity<TaskProto>().HasRequired(p => p.Group).WithMany(b => b.Tasks).Map(m => m.MapKey("Group_Id"));
```

Не помогло.

Comment: В пошаговой отладке посмотрите, на чем валится то.

Comment: При `db.Tasks.ToList();` и `db.Tasks.Add(tsk);`

Comment: Ну, тут уже очевиднее, что там где то исключение EF, ищите его. В логах, если наружу не вываливаются.

Comment: `The properties expression 't => t.AccountId' is not valid. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.. `

Comment: Убрал флуент, напилил аннотаций. Теперь такая ошибка: The `ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Account' on type 'Vikodin.Models.TaskProto' is not valid. The foreign key name 'AccountId' was not found on the dependent type 'Vikodin.Models.TaskProto'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.. `

Comment: Вам же прямым текстом пишет - должно быть свойством. Добавьте {get;set;} для полей, на которые ругается, чтобы они стали свойствами.

Comment: Вот что бывает когда кодишь в три ночи)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема была в `{get;set;}` у ключей `AccountId` и `GroupId`. Простейшая невнимательность с моей стороны. Спасибо всем кто помогал.